# Assert that a var is a non-empty string of no particular characters in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, assertions

I want to assert that a variable is a (non-blank) string in phpunit, but I don't want to assert that the string has to match any exact string.

For example, I want to pull a username, and ensure that I successfully got some non-blank username, but I don't care exactly which username I got.

I can pretty easily assert that it's a non-empty variable, or that it is a string exactly matching some string, or assert that the var is a string without phpunit's help:

```
$this->assertNotEmpty($username);
$this->assertSame('myusername', $username);
$this->assertTrue(is_string($username));
```

These are all close to what I need, with the use of is_string actually testing for the right conditions, but doing the is_string myself isn't quite good enough because when the test fail I can't get a useful, informative message any more, instead of telling me what type of value was actually returned, the error message becomes the useless:

```
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

So how can I assert that a var is of type string and non-blank using phpunit's assert system?

Comment: `$this->assertNotEquals("", $username);`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add your own messages to all  PHPUnit assertions, something like this should work for you:-

```
$this->assertTrue(is_string($username), "Got a " . gettype($username) . " instead of a string");
```

Otherwise, you could use

```
$this->assertInternalType('string', $username, "Got a " . gettype($username) . " instead of a string");
```

[See the manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertInternalType)

---

This answer is now outdated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66536551/212940) for the up to date solution.

Comment: assertInternalType looks like exactly what I'm looking for, I guess I was thrown off by the "Internal", thanks.

Comment: Came across this answer in 2020. With modern PHPUnit, `assertInternalType()` is deprecated, so instead, use $this->assertIsString($username)`.

Comment: Hard to deprecate a 37 vote answer, in favor of a 3 vote one (as of today), but @Szekelygobe's answer about 2018+ using type-specific `assertIs*()` is now the right answer

Answer (score 5):

From 2018 the `assertInternalType()` and `assertNotInternalType()` are depricated.

Use instead on of the following:

`assertIsArray()`

`assertIsBool()`

`assertIsFloat()`

`assertIsInt()`

`assertIsNumeric()`

`assertIsObject()`

`assertIsResource()`

`assertIsString()`

`assertIsScalar()`

`assertIsCallable()`

`assertIsIterable()`

`assertIsNotArray()`

`assertIsNotBool()`

`assertIsNotFloat()`

`assertIsNotInt()`

`assertIsNotNumeric()`

`assertIsNotObject()`

`assertIsNotResource()`

`assertIsNotString()`

`assertIsNotScalar()`

`assertIsNotCallable()`

`assertIsNotIterable()`